# Is it possible to connect a switching buck converter to a simple transformerless power supply?

Tags: buck, transformerless

Many cap based transformerless power supplies intended to use with 5V circuits, use a 5.6 zener diode to regulate ouput voltage. I'm using below circuit and the calculator [here](http://www.nomad.ee/micros/transformerless/index.shtml) [which is based on the well known microchip appnote A954] to calculate values. with `R1=33R` and `C1=1uF` the current usually is about `45mA` which is fine for many things, but a bit too low for my project.

[image: capacitor based transformerless power supply]

I thought I could use a higher voltage zener (e.g. 35V) and feed the output to a switching buck. with above values for C1,R1 and the 35V zener, the output voltage rises to `34V` (while the current is still at `45mA`) which is about `1.3W`. the 34V output is well in the range of super cheap `MC34063` converters in buck configuration (with the circuit provided in datasheet). this way, with the worst case of 70% efficiency, the buck can output 5V, up to 180mA which is enough for my purpose.

one problem is, that the D1 (zener diode) calculated power dissipation is about 2.5W and the suggested real power handling is double. so a 5W zener diode is required which is hard to come by in my local stores.

1. Is the whole idea applicable?
2. Is there any workaround to use a lower power rated zener diode instead? my connected device is always on and draws at least 50mA.

-- I'm well aware of risks of non-isolated supply. The project is a remote controlled light dimmer with some added things and is out of reach of people

Comment: Though not recommended you can parallel zener diodes. One with the lowest clamp will tend to dominate so low ohm series resistors help balance out differences. In fact to make that work you would have to pick and test them to find those with very close clamp voltage. Consider using a transformer, as working off-line can be dangerous.

Comment: I'm never very comfortable with non-isolated mains connected supplies.  There are lots of safety implications that many people don't understand.  Why not use a small isolated flyback supply instead? By the time you add the buck converter you're at about the same size anyway.  A small mains-USB phone charger (reference designs are easily available with off-the-shelf magnetics) can supply 5W and you don't have to have a zener that's dissipating lots of power.  See: https://www.ti.com/store/ti/en/p/product/?p=UCC28704EVM-724